# use subscribe() asynchronously

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous

**function definition**

```
resetComponent(){
  console.log("1st");
  ...
  this.background = { };
  this.uploadMode = false;
  this.service.getItem(this.watch.appId, true).subscribe((watch) => {
    this.background = { ... };
    console.log("2nd");
  }, ()=> {});
}
```

**my code**

```
console.log("before resetComponent()");
resetComponent();
console.log("after resetComponent()");
```

It doesn't work with asynchronous.

I'd like to see the console like this

```
before resetComponent()
1st
2nd
after resetComponent()
```

I don't fully understand `async`.

How can I achieve my goal?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to wait for the subscription to be completed before you can use it anyway?

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, I just want to see the console like that. :)

Comment: what are you getting as an error/output? And by doesnt work does that mean there is an error or nothing prints at all?

Comment: Add an error method in your subscribe then emit the event. If that doesn't work the problem is most likely the event your service is emitting

Answer (score 2):

Once you call **subscribe()** your code will continue to run and your subscription will run *asynchronously*.

You'll want something like this. You'll want to use **pipe** here instead of subscribe. Make sure you **return** your observable so you can subscribe to it later. :

```
resetComponent() {
    console.log("1st");
    this.background = {};
    this.uploadMode = false;
    return this.service.getItem(this.watch.appId, true).pipe((watch) => {
            this.background = { ... };
            console.log("2nd");
        }, () => { });
    }
```

Then call it using subscribe.

```
console.log("before resetComponent()");
resetComponent().subscribe(() => {
     console.log("after resetComponent()");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to view this video about the [**async JavaScript by Traversy Media**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PoRJizFvM7s) to better understand what is asynchronicity in browsers.

> It basically means a way for the browser to keep working without having to wait for something that might take some time(like a network request of a DOM Event or a call to the **`setTimeout`** method).
>
> Now browsers are single threaded so they use something called an Event Loop to perform asynchronicity. If you're interested in understanding what event loops are, there's a great talk about [**Event Loops by Philip Roberts here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ).

Now that we're on the same page(*hoping that you've watched the above videos :)* ), you can basically return an `Observable` from the `resetComponent()` method and then inside the `subscribe` to it, you can log **`after resetComponent()`** to the console.

Since you're not doing any sorts of transformations with the response inside the `resetComponent()` method, in order to achieve this, you can use the [**`tap`**](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/do.html) operator. And then return the `Observable` with it.

And you can then `subscribe` to the Observable returned by the `resetComponent()` method. This is how it would look like in code:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { DataService } from "./data.service";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = "Angular";
  background;
  uploadMode;
  watch = { appId: "something" };

  constructor(private service: DataService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("before resetComponent()");
    this.resetComponent().subscribe(res =>
      console.log("after resetComponent()")
    );
  }

  resetComponent() {
    console.log("1st");
    this.background = {};
    this.uploadMode = false;
    return this.service.getItem(this.watch.appId, true).pipe(
      tap(watch => {
        this.background = { watch };
        console.log("2nd");
      })
    );
  }
}
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5xebmd?file=src/app/app.component.ts) for your ref.